# How can I get pstoedit to handle CID Type0C fonts as text?

Tags: pdf, svg, fonts, ghostscript

I am trying to convert a pdf into an svg.  The problem is that the text is converted to paths, instead of text elements.

I create the pdf with "mutool draw" (no options).

The output of pdffonts on the created pdf:

```
Syntax Warning: Mismatch between font type and embedded font file
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
ArialMT                              CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes no  yes      8  0
```

I then call pstoedit (without options) to convert the pdf to an svg.  The verbose output includes the ghostscript call:

```
now calling the interpreter via: /usr/bin/gs -dDELAYBIND -dWRITESYSTEMDICT -dESTACKPRINT -dNODISPLAY -dNOEPS  "/home/chris/Documents/TTC/InteractiveSchematics/01conversion/psinW0yKlN"
GPL Ghostscript 9.10 (2013-08-30)
Copyright (C) 2013 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
Warning: ArialMT seems to be a non text font - you may want to use -dt or -adt.
Warning: ArialMT seems to be a non text font - you may want to use -dt or -adt.
Warning: ArialMT seems to be a non text font - you may want to use -dt or -adt.
Warning: ArialMT seems to be a non text font - you may want to use -dt or -adt.
Warning: ArialMT seems to be a non text font - you may want to use -dt or -adt.
Warning: ArialMT seems to be a non text font - you may want to use -dt or -adt.

These warnings are repeated ad nauseam...
```

The resultant svg file looks great, but the text is not searchable/selectable.  Can anyone help to this end?  I'd like to better understand this font business...

Comment: CIDFonts are *much* more complex than regular fonts, and can contain more than 255 glyphs. pstoedit can only handle ASCII encoded text, which isn't going to be the case for most PDF files. Try using the txtwrite device instead which can output Unicode, but be aware this is only going to work if the PDF has a ToUnicode CMap, and I rather doubt that the MuPDF PDF file will have one. I believe that svg doesn't deal well with fonts (I am no expert), so it may be that it can't handle Unicode either.

Comment: Thanks, Ken, but I need the text to be displayed nicely in addition to searchable/selectable.  I've started playing around with other tools including pstops and inkscape cmd-line to try to get a working combination.  Hopefully I'll find something...